# Looking for a word which implies the inability to change (not inexorable)

Tags: single-word-requests

The word can be used to show that someone (repeatedly) fails to change their habits. For instance, if someone has a tendency to steal, and you've consistently seen them stealing, you could use this word to describe them.

All I know is that it starts with *in* and the word isn't 'inexorable.'

Comment: "Never fails to change" means "always changes". Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: oops phrased it wrongly. its incorrigible thanks to the guy who replied.

Comment: Pathological comes to mind

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A related word is *[incorrigible](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/incorrigible)*, meaning uncorrectable. The word is used of people and their (bad) behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

A couple of possibilities, definitions from [Merriam-Webster](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/):

[**intractable:**](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/intractable) not easily governed, managed or directed; not disposed to be taught, disciplined, or tamed; obstinate; refractory

[**inveterate:**](https://unabridged.merriam-webster.com/unabridged/inveterate) 2c: stubbornly inflexible: adamant, obstinate
2d: long-lasting: persistent
4: fixed by long habit or usage : confirmed, habitual